# Database Sequence in PySpark

Tags: pyspark

Wanted to get database sequence for multiple values.

I have a data frame,
`df_data = df.groupBy("name").count()`

[image]

Am getting database sequence using,

```
df_seq = spark.read \
     .format("jdbc") \
     .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://xxxx:xxxx/xx" \
     .option("query", "select nextval('seq_name') as seq\
     .option("user", "qqqq") \
     .option("password", "wwww").load()
```

When i join df_data and df_seq, the result is,

[image]

Expected result is,

[image]

Any suggestion would be appreciated to get the sequence for each record from the database.